# Calling Graphics From Another Class

Tags: java, graphics, repaint

I'm trying to create a two player game, that uses keyboard input to move the players. So far when I test it from it's own class it works and I can move the players but when I call it from my game class it doesn't work. I'm also having this problem with graphics in another class as well. They show up but don't move. 
I'm not sure if I'm calling it wrong or if there is something I need to add. I think it might have to do with how I repaint it but I'm not sure.

Code where I paint the different graphics( this is in my game class):

```
     public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        aa.begin(g, -450);
        aa.Menu(g);
        if (running == true){
            g.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            one.healthbar(g);
            two.healthbar(g);
            one.drawplayer(g);
            two.drawplayer(g);
            aa.timer(g,0);
        }
     }

   @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         //running = true;
         //Run();  
     }
```

Code for One of my Player Class:

```
public class PlayerOne extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    private int x = 10, y = 10, velx = 0, vely = 0;
    public static int healthOne = 200;
    int power = 5;
    Timer tm = new Timer(5, this);
    boolean playing = true;

    public PlayerOne(){
        tm.start();
        InputMap im = getInputMap(JPanel.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        ActionMap am = getActionMap();

        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0, false), "W.pressed");
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0, true), "W.released");
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, 0, false), "S.pressed");
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, 0, true), "S.released");
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0, false), "A.pressed");
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0, true), "A.released");
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0, false), "D.pressed");
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0, true), "D.released");

        am.put("W.pressed", new MoveAction(-1, 0));
        am.put("W.released", new MoveAction(0, 0));
        am.put("S.pressed", new MoveAction(1, 0));
        am.put("S.released", new MoveAction(0, 0));
        am.put("A.pressed", new MoveAction(0, -1));
        am.put("A.released", new MoveAction(0, 0));
        am.put("D.pressed", new MoveAction(0, 1));
        am.put("D.released", new MoveAction(0, 0));  
    }
    //@Override
    /*public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 30, 30);
        healthbar(g);
    }*/
    public void drawplayer (Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 30, 30);
    }

    public void healthbar (Graphics g){

        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillRect(0, 640, healthOne, 25);
        //health -=20;
        repaint();

    }

    public class MoveAction extends AbstractAction {

        private int yDelta;
        private int xDelta;

        public MoveAction(int yDelta, int xDelta) {
            this.yDelta = yDelta;
            this.xDelta = xDelta;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            vely = yDelta;
            velx = xDelta;
        }
    }    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        repaint();
        x += velx;
        y += vely;

    }
}
```

Comment: `new Timer(5, this);` probably not enough time to actually draw anything.  Try 100 ms to start with, you can tighten that up later once you get things working.

Comment: I tried that but it's doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried calling `repaint` from a method that isn't doing any drawing?

Comment: I found out the problem I forgot to add in repaint in my paint method.